# sql insert into values The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, identifier

I am trying to run this command which shoulld append 80 rows.. but i get.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Frame.Guid" could not be bound.

```
 INSERT  INTO  studentrecords(recordGuid, studentGuid, courseGuid, licenseGuid, repeatflag, frameGuid, coredata, framescore, timeinframe, locked, daterefreshed, dateinserted)
 VALUES     (NEWID(), '25d6e1d9-e5ce-42dd-bd6a-5956ec7cb047', '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e', '00000000-1111-1111-0000-000000000000', 0, Frame.Guid,  '<flags><flag1>1</flag1> <flag2>1</flag2> <flag3>1</flag3> <flag4>1</flag4> <flag5>1</flag5><flag6>1</flag6></flags><StudentAnswer> <CorrectionHistory></CorrectionHistory> </StudentAnswer>', 0, 55860, 1, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
 Select Frame.Guid FROM Frame
 WHERE  (Frame.Course = '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e') AND (Frame.Template <> '7d3a3b40-86e3-43f4-a4ca-039afdd0b7a3')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO studentrecords (
                            recordGuid, studentGuid, courseGuid, licenseGuid, 
                            repeatflag, frameGuid, coredata, 
                            framescore, timeinframe, locked, 
                            daterefreshed, dateinserted
                           ) 
   SELECT NEWID(), 
          '25d6e1d9-e5ce-42dd-bd6a-5956ec7cb047', 
          '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e', 
          '00000000-1111-1111-0000-000000000000', 
          0, Frame.Guid, '1 1 1 1 11 ', 0, 55860, 1, 
          GETDATE(), GETDATE() 
     FROM Frame 
    WHERE Frame.Course = '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e'
          AND Frame.Template <> '7d3a3b40-86e3-43f4-a4ca-039afdd0b7a3';
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how you want the "insert" and "select" queries here to be related -- they're both syntactically complete but not linked in any way. You're expecting "Frame.Guid" in the first query to come from the second query, somehow, but I can't quite get how. In any case, that's all that the error message is saying; it can't tell what you mean by Frame.Guid, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `Frame.Guid` in the insert statement, but there isn't one defined.  I suspect you want to select that value into a variable, then use the variable in the insert statement.

```
DECLARE @frameGUID GUID

SET @frameGUID = (Select Frame.Guid FROM Frame
WHERE  (Frame.Course = '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e')
   AND (Frame.Template <> '7d3a3b40-86e3-43f4-a4ca-039afdd0b7a3'))

INSERT  INTO  studentrecords(recordGuid, studentGuid, courseGuid, licenseGuid, repeatflag, frameGuid, coredata, framescore, timeinframe, locked, daterefreshed, dateinserted)
VALUES  (
    NEWID(),
    '25d6e1d9-e5ce-42dd-bd6a-5956ec7cb047',
    '54dffd58-1af9-44cf-982e-ea0e8930878e',
    '00000000-1111-1111-0000-000000000000',
    0,
    @frameGUID,
    '<flags><flag1>1</flag1> <flag2>1</flag2> <flag3>1</flag3> <flag4>1</flag4> <flag5>1</flag5><flag6>1</flag6></flags><StudentAnswer> <CorrectionHistory></CorrectionHistory> </StudentAnswer>',
    0,
    55860,
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two statements there. The `INSERT` statement has no way of knowing that you want the field `Frame.Guid` out of the `SELECT` statement.

You need to refactor it into one statement. You can do that by putting all the constants into the `SELECT` statement (between `SELECT` and `FROM`) and deleting the `VALUES` clause. Then it will be one statement.